# How can I include only one folder from another repository in Git?

Tags: python, git, git-submodules

I have a python module which looks like this.

```
|
|-- my_module/
|-- tests/
|-- .git/
```

I'd like to use it in another project. Normally submodules would suffice, however, I'd rather just drop in the actual module without including anything else into my app like so.

```
|-- .git/
|-- my_app/
|-- my_module/
```

Is there a way to only import a single folder using a git submodule?

> If I can't or if it's impractical, how else can I include a single folder from another git-tracked project while keeping it version controlled?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish not to use git `submodule` you can simply checkout the desired folder.

Since there is no explicit way to grab only folder from the repo you will have to something manually like this:

```
- create your desired repositories (you already have it)
- write a script that loop over range of commits
- extract the desired folder content from the current commit
- commit the current folder
```

The problem with this is that you will not have the original SHA-1 since you only committing partial section of the commit snapshot.

#### Code sample

Your code should look something like:

```
for commit in $(git rev-list $branch)
do
    if git ls-tree --name-only -r $commit | grep '<your desired path>'; then
        // Process the commit content
        git checkout <path>
        git add ....
        git commit .... 
        exit 0
    fi
done
```

#### Why cant I just pull out folder form git history?

The reason is simply the way git store its content.

> Git is stupid content tracker (Linus Tovalds)

Which means that git doesn't store the content in the same way we see it in our working directory.

Git simply take a **snapshot** of the current file system (In real its little bit more complicated and git use blobs, hunks, heuristics and much more) so in order to extract specific content from the history you must `checkout` the specific content from the the `commit` itself.

Comment: This would certainly be a desired feature of git, thanks for the (presumably) bash script. Side node: are there other sane VC systems that that can do this?

Comment: So far i have not ran into something like it.

Answer (score 0):

Git subtree might work in this case. You could subtree add the other repo into yours, and then delete the folders you don't care about in a second commit.

However, when you later subtree update to get a new version of the other repo, you will need to handle any merge conflicts if there are changes in your deleted folders.

If your other project is going to be updating frequently, this probably isn't a good solution.